# Working with sass in firefox (48<)

Tags: firefox, sass, gulp

I have a pretty basic setup. Gulp watching and compiling sass files. So after enabling source files in ff  I can see that there are sass files linked to the page. Problem is that when I change them and try to save them (under source files tab) I get a prompt – asking where is the sass file located. I select the correct sass file, gulp changes the file but Firefox doesn’t see it- after saving it, I get a prompt that it can’t find anymore that sass file.

In chrome it works fine. Tried to google it but it seems like nobody is using Firefox and sass?
Maybe you have a working solution how to work with ff and sass?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you edit the source in FF's Developer Tools' Style Editor tab, save the changes and overwrite the original file, that triggers gulp to compile the Sass to CSS, and that makes the page fail to load in FF?

Comment: No, it fails to load scss file. I've attached an image. Strange thing is when I try to save edits to the scss file, ff asks for the css files and not scss. I select the scss any way and after reload file  disappears (pic3).
Whole setup works flawlessly on chrome.
Although I have a suspicion that ff is mapping the file incorrectly. When you map scss files in chrome it's in "source" and not from the physical path itself,
To be honest I am a bit puzzled that there is so little info about working with sass and ff.

Comment: I'm getting closer to understanding the situation. So are you saying that you edit the source in FF's Developer Tools' Style Editor tab, save the changes and overwrite the original file, reload the page, and the changes you made are gone?